# Cast troubles while using LINQ to filter a Dictionary by values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got a `Dictionary<string,int>` with a few values in it.  For example:

- "a", 600
- "b", 550
- "c", 400

I want to filter this list to keep values that are greater than 500.  I don't use C# very often, and haven't used any LINQ.  I thought that this might be a good time to learn.  So, I have tried the following:

```
Dictionary<string,int> someDictionary = new Dictionary();

// Code to populate someDictionary goes here

someDictionary = (Dictionary<string,int>) someDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value > 500);
```

This throws an InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]'.

I've tried a handful of casts, calls to `.ToDictionary()`, etc.  I cannot seem to figure out how to cast this correctly, or get the syntax quite right.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use ToDictionary, then pass the selector for the key, then the selector for the value.

```
someDictionary = someDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value > 500)
                               .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```